# What's Wrong LED conversion

Tags: conversion

Greeting.  I am converting my garage fixtures from flourescent to LED. Accordingly, I chose a single end plug-in install. So, I went out & purchased a pair of GE T8 light changing 4 ft  LED bulbs. I removed the ballast, pig tailed a pair of tombstone sockets on the power end, both with a black & white wire. I connected the white wires together with the white wire from the power cord & soldered them together put a wire nut on it and added a piece of electrical tape to secure the wire nut. Did the same with the black or hot wire, put the lamp back together, plugged it in. NOTHING! I can't imagine what I did wrong. Help & thanks.

Comment: Usually, these replacement lamps come with a very specific diagram. Did you follow that diagram? Also a **photo** of the connections would help to understand the issue.

Comment: *soldered them together* - Generally soldering is not used with 120V or 240V wiring. More common is wire nuts or Wago connectors.

Comment: I went through an absolute headache of a conversion a while back. I had appropriate voltages at the tombstones and no light. It turned out the bulbs I had gotten weren't compatible with the tombstones in my fixture. Weirdest thing to figure out. I returned them for another brand, and those worked instantly.

Comment: You wired it for single-ended configuration (one tombstone completely dead, the other having both hot and neutral).  That is not the only way to wire LED conversions; many are double-ended (one tombstone both pins hot, the other tombstone both pins neutral).  I wonder if that plays a role.  I find reputable manufacturers strongly lean toward the double-ended arrangement, I'm a bit surprised to hear of a GE single-ended.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question>  KMJ got it right. The bulbs that I bought were not the right ones for a direct conversion. Just want to pass on another morsel of knowledge that these new LED lamps can be more fragile than the flourescent version. Might I suggest that rather than twisting them in place on the holders, don't do it with the glass tube portion. Do it with the ends. case closed and thank you all for your help.,